# Custom error message with DataAnnotationsExtensions

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I'm trying to get Scott Kirkland's DataAnnotationsExtensions to work with my MVC4 project. But I'm having problems with the client side validation of an email address. I've added a EmailAddress annotation with a error message, but when I enter an invalid email address I do not get the custom error message, but instead I get the generic email error message "Please enter a valid RecipientEmail address.".

My class looks like this:

```
public class NpRequest
{
    [DisplayName("Telefonnummer som skal overdrages")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Angiv telefonnummeret som skal overdrages")]
    public string PhoneNumer { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Recipient email address")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "This is my custom error message")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The recipient email address is required")]
    public string RecipientEmail { get; set; }
    public RecipientTypeEnum RecipientType { get; set; }
}
```

And my view:

---SNIPPET BEGIN---

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumer)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumer)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumer)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecipientEmail)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecipientEmail)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecipientEmail)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
```

---SNIPPET END---

EDIT:
When I inspect the HTML it looks like this:

```
<input class="text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-email="This is my custom error message" data-val-required="The recipient email address is required" id="RecipientEmail" name="RecipientEmail" type="email" value="">
```

It seems that my custom error message is put into the data-val-email attribute. I was under the impression that the DataAnnotationExtension automatically added my custom error message to the ModelState and thereby also adding it to the field-validation-error span, which is showing the MVC validation error.

Is this assumption wrong? Should I write my own javascript, which extracts the custom error message attribute and injects it into the field-validation-error span?

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did u inspect the Recepient Email `Textbox` and check if the error message in Data- attribute is same as mentioned in the `Model` Validation rule? Is there any `Js` running to show the custom error message ?

Comment: Edited question and added the emitted HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a mix of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and DataAnnotationsExtensions.  I found out out that most of the time data annotations will also make client side validation. The only time where is no client side validation, is when I check if the phone number is the correct length.

```
public class NpRequest
{
    [DisplayName("Phone number")]
    [MinLengthAttribute(8, ErrorMessage = "Phone number must be 8 digits")]
    [MaxLengthAttribute(8, ErrorMessage = "Phone number must be 8 digits")]
    [DigitsAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Phone number must be 8 digits")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Modtagers email adresse")]
    [EmailAddressAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    public string RecipientEmail { get; set; }
    public RecipientTypeEnum RecipientType { get; set; }
}
```